# Not sure I can code an app for my Magento store! Any better alternative for the same?

Tags: magento2, mobile

I am an Magento eCommerce store manager & planning to extend my business to mobile as well. Tried my hands on coding but isn't my cup of tea. Hope you all help me with some solution.

Comment: Magento has the rest API which you can use for Data provide for  Mobile APPS https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/index.html. You can use  PWA https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/pwa/ which help  for increase your store business.

Answer (score 0):

I can easily relate to your situation there. Few months back even I was in the search of some code-free option. Someone suggested me this magento mobile app extension which offered fully developed apps for my website with complete support. 
Here are the info for your ease:

[Magento 1](https://www.knowband.com/magento-mobile-app-builder)

[Magento 2](https://www.knowband.com/magento-2-mobile-app-builder)

Hope this helps you!